# How to arrange the data from ListView exactly below the labels using xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

I want to arrange the data from ListView to be exactly below  the Labels.

For now ListView look like this:

[image: ListView]

What is the option to arrange the data just above of labels ?

My Code:

```
 <StackLayout>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label  TextColor="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Text="Станция:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Име:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Дата:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Мин. Стоеж:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Ср. Стоеж:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Макс. Стоеж:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Делта:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Макс. Делта:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                </Grid>

            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                <ListView x:Name="lstLevel" HasUnevenRows="True" BackgroundColor="#f7f77c">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.View>
                                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#f7f77c">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="2"></RowDefinition>

                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Station}" XAlign="Start" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Ime}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Dat, StringFormat='{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding MinStoej}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding AvgStoej}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding MaxStoej}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding Delta}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding DeltaMax}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <BoxView Color="#001aff" HeightRequest="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="9"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ViewCell.View>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
```

I think the columns are correct, but the data from the grid itself needs to be shifted to the left.
What is the right approach to do this?

Comment: don't use `*` for the widths of your columns

Comment: Can I use auto ?

Comment: no, because you want to force two different grids to use the same column widths

Comment: What can I use ?

Comment: use proportional sizes - see @amjad's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try add the grid in listview header with same colm width.

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewm" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListView.Header>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label  TextColor="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Text="Станция:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Име:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Дата:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Мин. Стоеж:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Ср. Стоеж:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Макс. Стоеж:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Делта:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                    <Label Text="Макс. Делта:" BackgroundColor="#6588cf" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="15"/>
                
        </Grid>
    </ListView.Header>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Station}" XAlign="Start" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Ime}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Dat, StringFormat='{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding MinStoej}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding AvgStoej}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding MaxStoej}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding Delta}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding DeltaMax}" XAlign="Center" YAlign="Center" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
                                        <BoxView Color="#001aff" HeightRequest="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="9"/>
                                   
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```